# Flutter & Android Studio - Trying to run a flutter app on an android emulator via Android Studio, but emulator is greyed out

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to run a flutter app on the android emulator via Android Studio on a Mac, but the virtual device option is greyed out, even though I created the virtual device. I don't have Xcode installed. See attached link:

[Screenshot of android virtual device emulator greyed out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A383A.png)

I tried installing various SDK tools, restarted my Mac, and nothing has worked so far.

[Screenshot of SDK tools installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQwjL.png)

When I run `flutter emulators`, it shows that there's one available, and that's the virtual device I created, so flutter does recognise it.

```
Pixel_4_XL_API_30 • Pixel 4 XL API 30 • Google • android
```

Here's the output for `flutter doctor`.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
  Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
  Or install Xcode via the App Store.
  Once installed, run:
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
✗ CocoaPods not installed.
    CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side`s plugin code that responds to your
    plugin usage on the Dart side.
    Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
    For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
  To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.70.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Is the missing CocoaPods the issue?